# Is there a way to 'inject' a command line output into another command?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line

for ex :

```
grep -R "requests" /some/really/long/path/to/type/out
```

I would like to do something like this

```
grep -R "requests" (pwd)
```

Basically, using the output of pwd sorta like a pipe (pipe dosent do it).

Comment: @choroba's answer has the generic solution; in your specific case, however, simply using the `PWD` _variable_ should do: `"$PWD"`.

Comment: How about using `grep -R "requests" .` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use command substitution:

```
grep -R "requests" $(pwd)
```

The output of the command in `$(...)` is used as an argument list to the command. If you want the output to be treated as one word, wrap it in double quotes:

```
ls "$( command-that-produces-dirname-containing-whitespace )"
```

Comment: In this case you'll certainly want to quote `$(pwd)`.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can use backtics for this:

```
grep -R "requests" `pwd`
```

`pwd` will be executed and the stdout of pwd will be used as the third parameter of the grep command

Comment: This is the same as the other answer, as `$()` and `` have the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes, but it is also a answer to the question